# Can Java Web Start be configured to update the current server version instead of the latest?

Tags: java, java-web-start

Summarizing my research so far it seems as if Java Web Start will use the timestamp provided via a web server to determine whether a certain jar has been updated or not. The update behaviour can be influenced by the jnlp element "update" where elements "check" and "policy" which allow to define how often an update check will be done and whether the user is prompted to confirm the update or not.

However I did not find any opportunity to define another mechanism than the timestamp comparison to determine if an application has been updated or not. Actually we're having a discussion at the moment if it makes more sense (for us) if not the newest, but the current server version should be downloaded to the client. This could also e.g. be an older server version which has been restored on the server, because a formerly active newer server version has been rolled backed. 
In case of a server-sided application rollback every user has to manually clear its Java cache at the moment, which is of course possible but not very convenient.

Can Java Web Start be configured/forced to always download the application version from the server if this is "different" from the locally cached version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't konw if it exactly meets your need, but have a look at webstart's [Version Download Protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/avoidingUnnecessaryUpdateChecks.html).

To sum  it up:
With versioned download you can specify each jar-version to be used in the jnlp-file like this:

```
    <jar href="jackson-core.jar" version="2.0.2" />
```

and deploy your jar-file on the server  with a filename of `jackson-core__V2.0.2.jar`.

With this protocol webstart will only use jar-files whose version exactly matches the given version from the jnlp-file. Another advantage is, that when the specified version is already present in the local cache webstart will not try to download the version again - regardless of timestamps etc.

Advantages:

- Full control over versions used via jnlp-file.
- Less download-requests for jars present in cache

Disadvantages:

- New versions require a change in the jnlp-file
- Not suitable for SNAPSHOT-builds since the file's timestamp is completely ignored and version-numbers don't change for SNAPSHOT-builds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I see that this is in general a way to force a certain jar version to be loaded, but in our case we have a lot of customers who are using a "customized" jnlp version. Therefore we try to keep the number of mandatory changes to our "default" jnlp file as low as possible, to avoid "manual merges". So in this case the cache deletion (or timestamp adjustment on the server) is the smaller trouble to us.